# How to change default language in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want my site to only be in swedish language. How to accomplish this?

In my lang/sv/ folder I have six files.

auth.php

pagination.php

passwords.php

sv.json

validation-inline.php

validation.php

The page source says html lang="sv" but everything is in english.

Also the email verification is in english.

This is what I have done so far.

In app\config\app.php I have change this

```
'locale' => 'sv',

'fallback_locale' => 'sv',
```

In my terminal I have run these commands.

composer dump-autoload

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan event:clear

php artisan optimize:clear

What else can I do?

I'm using Laravel 8.12.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had the sv.json file in the wrong folder.
It should be in lang folder not in lang\sv\ folder.